# Why is breakthrough voltage of a TVS-diode decreasing when in parallel with an inductance

Tags: diodes, inductance

in our lab we are testing a circuit which has an inductance and a TVS-Diode in parallel. The task is it to determine the breakthrough voltage of the diode.

The test works like this:
We apply a voltage of 24V to the circuit and then instantly switch off the supply voltage via a relay. We then measure the induced voltage of the circuit. You can see the voltage in the picture below.

[image: The Graph shows the induced voltage over time]

My Question now is: Why is the cut-off not horizontal (for example constant -48V). Instead you can see a change in voltage from -50V to -48V.
We assume that the time response of the diode has something to do with it.

The TVS-Diode used is this one: http://www.vishay.com/docs/88301/15ke.pdf.

I hope someone can elaborate on the phenomenon.
Thank you in advance.
ELWI

Comment: How much current? You are probably heating up the die inside it which will shift the clamp voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TVS device clamping voltage is proportional to clamping current.

This excerpt from the datasheet shows this:

[image: TVS data]

The highlight in red is the nominal break-over voltage at a specific test current (1mA in this case).

The orange highlight is the maximum peak current and the blue highlight is the voltage across the device at that maximum clamping current. Note that the clamping voltage can be as high as 70.1V for a nominal 51V device.

When you switch your circuit off, a large current flows which will decrease exponentially; with this variation of current, you will see a variation of clamping voltage.

Your plot is perfectly normal for this device.